# Enable cross-origin isolation headers without refresh

Tags: next.js

I am building a social media application, and I am using [ffmpeg.wasm](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm) for local video encoding/upload.

I want to use multi-threading for ffmpeg with SharedArrayBuffer and for this I need to enable cross-origin isolation.

The side effect of this is that images cannot be shown from other sources on the main media feed.

My current solution is to only enable cross-origin isolation headers on /upload in next.config.js:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/upload',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy',
            value: 'require-corp',
          },
          {
            key: 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy',
            value: 'same-origin',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

The problem is, this solution only works after a refresh on the /upload page. At the moment, I force a reload with router.reload(), but this results in a long loading screen and might put users in a loop.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `credentialless` instead of `require-corp` for the `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy`? Per the docs it seems like that should be acceptable when using SharedArray Buffer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy

If I'm understanding it correctly, that should allow you to load images from external domains.

Comment: @rfestag That seems to have worked! I just applied it to all pages with /:path*{/}? and now it works! I see it is a experimental feature so I never came across it until now, thanks!

Comment: You can add the attribute `crossorigin="anonymous"` on your image tags. I got it fixed that way. Using `credentialess` is not a solution in my case as I need to support Firefox and Safari. Also, make sure your image responses headers contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` or 'mydomain.com'.